# How to get random speech

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make simple program with speech and can't figure out how to make it say random things. That's what i did but it doesnt work. I found on google examples but only with numbers and i am not sure how to do it. So, how to make the program speak random "Hello, Hi or Hey" ?

```
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim SAPI
        Dim r As Random = New Random
        SAPI = CreateObject("SAPI.spvoice")
        SAPI.Speak(r.Next("Hello", "Hi", "Hey"))
    End If
```

Comment: First show us what you have that works and what doesn't.  I'd recommend taking the random feature out of your code until you can make it say _something_ then add features.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using the classes in the `System.Speech` assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a string array and randomise the values that are being called.

```
Dim speech() As String = {"Hello", "Hi", "Howdy"}

If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    Dim SAPI
    Dim r As Random = New Random
    SAPI = CreateObject("SAPI.spvoice")
    SAPI.Speak(speech(r.Next(0, speech.Length)))
End If
```